# How can I get the response of request of API on ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I am currently working on a project that I have to make a specific method.
By using this method, I want to get the result as Json.
url is completely fine and it returns Json when I hit it by Curl -get command.
and It returns something like this
[{id: "~~~", name: "~~~"}, {id: "===", name: "==="}]

```
  def api(url)
    uri = URI.parse(url)
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    https.use_ssl = true
    res = https.request(req)
    res.to_json ( i also tried res.body)
  end
```

I want to solve this, I did not find out the problem though.

*Added

I have just found out that res = https.request(req) is not functioning.
print res returns nothing.

In this class, I added these requires but maybe there's something wrong with around here.

```
  require 'json'
  require 'net/http'
  require 'uri'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the response body:

```rb
JSON.parse(res.body)
```

The example of getting results from JSONPlacehoder service in a pure IRB session.

```rb
irb(main):001:0> require 'json'
=> true
irb(main):002:0>   require 'net/http'
=> true
irb(main):003:0>   require 'uri'
=> false
irb(main):004:1* def api(url)
irb(main):005:1*   uri = URI.parse(url)
irb(main):006:1*   req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
irb(main):007:1*   https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
irb(main):008:1*   https.use_ssl = true
irb(main):009:1*   res = https.request(req)
irb(main):010:1*   JSON.parse(res.body)
irb(main):011:0> end
=> :api
irb(main):012:0> url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos'
irb(main):013:0> api(url)
=> [{"userId"=>1, "id"=>1, "title"=>"delectus aut autem", "completed"=>false}, {"userId"=>1, "id"=>2, "title"=>"quis ut nam facilis et officia qui", "completed"=>false}, {"userId"=>1, "id"=>3, "title"=>"fugiat veniam minus", "completed"=>false}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment but somehow I cannot get results.
it seems that this part doesn't work `res = https.request(req)`

Comment: It works well, please check out my update. There might be other issues related to the URL that you use.